Snowflake Cortex Semantic model
To generate sql queries one needs to create a semantic model in yaml file? Do I end up creating one semantic file for all database objects or you could create multiple and Cortex would refer to all yaml files?
I am new to Cortex and trying to understand the way to implement it.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
